# Guarantee on filter + iterator on a stream

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream

I am iterating using iterator over a stream, like this:

```
Iterator<A> it = myAs.stream().filter(a -> a.isOk()).iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    A a = it.next();
    a.update();
}
```

In my case, it is possible that by updating the `A` at the beginning of `myAs`, I impact the `.isOk()` condition on later `A` in the list.

Is it guaranteed that the filtering condition `a -> a.isOk()` on the ith element of the stream is evaluated **after** the iteration of the 0...i-1 elements of the stream?

In other words, is this code equivalent to:

```
Iterator<A> it = myAs.stream().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    A a = it.next();
    if (a.isOk()) {
        a.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you saying that once you acquire the `myAs.stream()` and do something with that, somewhere else someone might update some contents of `myAs` as-well?

Comment: There is no such guaranty, but why do you expect performing `a.update()` to have an effect on the result of `a.isOk()` *of a different `a`*?

Comment: @Eugene No, I am only considering that by doing `a.update()` in the loop on, e.g., the 2nd `a`, this can impact the `a.isOk()` on a later `a`.

Comment: @Holger Because the `a`s can be linked in some way, e.g., the second `a` can hold a reference to the first `a` and use it in `isOk()`.

Comment: Then, you have interference and shouldn’t use the Stream API for that task. I don’t see the benefit of using the Stream API anyway, when you end up dealing with an `Iterator` manually. What about `for(A a: myAs) if(a.isOk()) a.update();`?

Comment: @Holger There are no benefits, I was just using this code before, and when looking back at it I thought it would fail when the `a` are linked, but it did not, so I just wanted to know if this was guaranteed.

Comment: In this particular example, using only stateless intermediate operations with a sequential stream, the processing order happens to match the encounter order, which gives you the desired result, even reproducible. Using it as a template for other operations may cause trouble in the future, which is the reason why you shouldn’t use an API against its intention.

Comment: @Holger What do you mean by *"using only stateless intermediate operations with a sequential stream"*? The only "state" of the operation (in the `filter()`) is the `a`, which can be impacted by prior `a`. And the evaluation of the `a`s will always be sequential, due to other constraints.

Comment: The *stream* is sequential, as you did not use `parallelStream()` nor `.parallel()`. It doesn’t matter why you use a sequential stream, the reason doesn’t change the fact that the example works *because* you’re using a sequential stream. The `filter` operation is a stateless intermediate operation *per definition* (which is why a stateful predicate is violating the contract). A counter-example would be `sorted`. When you add it between `filter(…)` and `iterator()`, all elements will be checked against the predicate, before your iterator even sees the first element.

Comment: @Holger So what you are saying is that the behavior is guaranteed in this case?

Comment: No, I’m saying, it is implemented in a way (and unlikely to be ever implemented differently) that makes this specific case do the desired thing. That’s different from being formally correct or even recommended. The general rule is that stream predicates should not depend on the processing order resp. there should be no interference between the terminal operation and the other intermediate operations.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this so I devised this to see if I understand the issue.  The following modifies an object and it does affect the filter.  I may not be understanding the issue though.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo[] arr = IntStream.range(1, 11).mapToObj(Foo::new).toArray(Foo[]::new);
      Iterator<Foo> it = Arrays.stream(arr).peek(System.out::println).filter(
            a -> a.v % 2 == 0).iterator();

      int count = 0;
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(it.next());
         if (count == 2) {
            arr[5].v = 1000; // not affected
            arr[6].v = 2000; // affected
         }
         count++;
      }
   }

}

class Foo {
   public int v;

   Foo(int v) {
      this.v = v;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return "Foo:" + v;
   }
}
```

Comment: You are only counting matching elements, so when `count == 2`, you just passed `arr[5]`. Put `System.out.println(it.next());` after the `if` statement, to see the effect. But this doesn’t answer the question whether the exhibited behavior *is guaranteed*.